# Apache Rewrite RULE

Tags: apache

Ok

can some one tell me what is wrong with this, i know it seems stupid but it is not working

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^(/mapa/mapa.htm) htp://www.domain.com/map`

i also try

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^(/mapa/mapa\.htm) htp://www.domain.com/map`

any ideas ?

Comment: maybe just a typo but your domain address missing a 't' at http

Comment: its ok i omit the t to avoid it to be show as a link

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^map/?$    mapa/mapa.htm    [L]
```

Comment: The ? means the / char is optional. So it can be mysite.com/map and mysite.com/map/

Maybe the relative path is the issue. Try putting absolute path instead of mapa/mapa.htm

Comment: Yeah, the full filesystem path to the mapa.htm file (that is if you're running this locally of course :)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help, i just remove the cache from my explorer and problem fix. It seem that the cache was showing me the old adress. I know it is crazy but what can i say.